EventEmitter related error on importing AzureClient from @fluidframework/azure-client in React app
Can't import the named export 'EventEmitter' (reexported as 'EventEmitter') from default-exporting module (only default export is available)
ERROR in ./node_modules/@fluid-internal/client-utils/lib/indexBrowser.js 12:0-50
Can't import the named export 'EventEmitter' (reexported as 'EventEmitter') from default-exporting module (only default export is available)
ERROR in ./node_modules/@fluid-internal/client-utils/lib/typedEventEmitter.js 12:39-51
Can't import the named export 'EventEmitter' (imported as 'EventEmitter') from default-exporting module (only default export is available)
webpack compiled with 2 errors
Here is the Code of the component:
import { useMsal } from "@azure/msal-react";
import { AzureClient } from "@fluidframework/azure-client";

export const generateFluidToken = async (
  tenantId,
  scopes = ["doc:read", "doc:write", "summary:write"],
  documentId
) => {
  const { instance } = useMsal();
  const Token = await instance.acquireTokenSilent({
    account: instance.getActiveAccount(),
  });

  const user = instance.getActiveAccount();
  const userName = user.name;
  const userId = user.username;

  const requestBody = {
    tenantId: tenantId,
    documentId: documentId,
    userId: userId,
    userName: userName,
    scopes: scopes,
  };
  console.log("requestBody", requestBody);
  try {
    const response = await fetch(process.env.REACT_APP_FLUID_FUNCTION_URL, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${Token.idToken}`,
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(requestBody),
    });

    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error(`HTTP error! status: ${response.status}`);
    }
    const fluidAccessToken = await response.json();
    return fluidAccessToken;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error generating token:", error);
  }
};

I get these errors when I try to import the AzureClient from @fluidframework/azure-client. This is a React JS app created using CRA.
This is indexBrowser.js
/*!
 * Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation and contributors. All rights reserved.
 * Licensed under the MIT License.
 */
// Entrypoint for browser-specific code in the package.
// (See 'Isomorphic Code' section in the package README.md.)
export { bufferToString, isArrayBuffer, IsoBuffer, stringToBuffer, Uint8ArrayToString, } from "./bufferBrowser.js";
export { gitHashFile, hashFile } from "./hashFileBrowser.js";
export { performance } from "./performanceIsomorphic.js";
export { fromBase64ToUtf8, fromUtf8ToBase64, toUtf8 } from "./base64EncodingBrowser.js";
export { Uint8ArrayToArrayBuffer } from "./bufferShared.js";
export { EventEmitter } from "./eventEmitter.cjs";
export { Trace } from "./trace.js";
export { TypedEventEmitter, } from "./typedEventEmitter.js";
//# sourceMappingURL=indexBrowser.js.map

This is typedEmitter.js

/*!
 * Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation and contributors. All rights reserved.
 * Licensed under the MIT License.
 */
import { EventEmitter } from "./eventEmitter.cjs";
/**
 * Event Emitter helper class the supports emitting typed events.
 * @privateRemarks
 * This should become internal once the classes extending it become internal.
 * @alpha
 */
export class TypedEventEmitter extends EventEmitter {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.addListener = super.addListener.bind(this);
        this.on = super.on.bind(this);
        this.once = super.once.bind(this);
        this.prependListener = super.prependListener.bind(this);
        this.prependOnceListener = super.prependOnceListener.bind(this);
        this.removeListener = super.removeListener.bind(this);
        this.off = super.off.bind(this);
    }
}
//# sourceMappingURL=typedEventEmitter.js.map

I have tried reinstalling node_modules, cleaning cache and changing node versions.

I was using CRA for the template creation. It was an issue with the way it handles the imports.
As it is already deprecated, It made sense for me to move to webpack. I used https://createapp.dev/webpack for my React project. I used webpack 5 which does have some known issues with the fluid framework, documented here
Webpack bundler worked perfectly fine with the fluid framework without any errors.
========== Update =============
Adding in a response that I got from issue that I had raised in microsoft/FluidFrmework. This should explain the issue in more details:
CRA (create-react-app) attempts to do some magic for management of polyfills as it does not directly expose webpack config.
Fluid Framework has reduced dependencies on Node.js core modules in 2.x but has not eliminated all of them. It is also common for any apps written on earlier versions of Fluid Framework to end up with a silent, direct Node.js module dependency and then those will persist even once Fluid Framework use has been eliminated. When the issue is missing polyfill, the error is not likely to be the above but a message that says Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '' in ... and goes on to talk about polyfills. In those situations, if the root dependency can't be eliminated, then simply adding a polyfill to local package production dependencies will likely resolve the issue.
For the original posted error, the most common successful resolution is to use a CRA customizer, such as https://www.npmjs.com/package/@craco/craco or https://www.npmjs.com/package/customize-cra. The issue is that webpack is not understanding how to handle a .cjs file. See facebook/create-react-app#10356 (comment) for some discussion of the issue. Once a configuration customizer is installed, the important rule to inject is:
config.module.rules.push({
test: /.[cm]js$/,
include: /node_modules/,
type: 'javascript/auto',
});
(Note that this rule handles both .cjs and .mjs. The referenced CRA issue only handles .mjs.)
